# Scrolling just part of the header and rest fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I ran into problem I cant solve whole night. Actually what I am looking for.
"Actual look and tool to explain what I am asking for"

[image]

I want the red part to scroll up, when I scroll, the blue part go on scroll up too, but on top:0px stop and become fixed, I guess it will be by jQuery and I am really bad at it, best would be just by css, due to mobile users. Can someone help me with that please? Here is my html markup

```
<header>
        <div ID="Banner">
            <br>
            <h1>RISTORANTE PIZZERIE NA HRADBÁCH</h1>
            <h3>ROZVOZ JÍDEL A PIZZY PO SLANÉM A OKOLÍ</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="Menu">

            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="homeButton" runat="server" Text="Domů" PostBackUrl="Home.aspx" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="dailyMenuButton" runat="server" Text="Denní Nabídka" PostBackUrl="DailyMenu.aspx" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="diningMenuButton" runat="server" Text="Jídelní Menu" PostBackUrl="DiningMenu.aspx" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="contactsButton" runat="server" Text="Kontakt" PostBackUrl="Contacts.aspx" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div ID="Content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! Got it working.

jQuery

```
var distance = $('#Menu').offset().top,
$window = $(window);

$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
        $("#Menu").addClass('MenuOnTop');
        $("#Content").addClass('ContentStep');
    } else {
        $("#Menu").removeClass('MenuOnTop');
        $("#Content").removeClass('ContentStep');
    }

});
});
```

CSS

```
.MenuOnTop {
position:fixed;
top: 0px;
width:100%;
}

    .ContentStep{
    margin-top:120px;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Biggest issue was using windows as variable nad overflow on body, for first didnt have set any, but setting visible did the job. Thanks Junaid Ahmed for kickup.

Comment: So, it means there was nothing wrong with my code from my answer but merely your CSS code had some properties conflicting with my JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with CSS only. Here's the jQuery to do this. I didn't test the code but let me know what the results are.

```
var $menu = $("#Menu"),
    menuStart = $menu.offset().top();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > menuStart ){
        $menu.addClass('menu-stick');
    } else {
        $menu.removeClass('menu-stick');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
#Menu {
   position: relative;
}

.menu-stick {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Play with the code, change code as you see fit. If still doesn't work, post your code again, we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Got it working, went out of your code and some research. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this in pure CSS by adding `position: sticky` to the navigation bar.

[Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

Comment: I am kinda worried of using sticky cus those bugs :/